# Terminal does not generate controller in the editor

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, controller

I am new to programming in Ruby and Rails. I am following the instructions to generate a new controller (rails generate controller welcome index). In the terminal, it creates correctly the controller, it appears:

```
create  app/controllers/welcome_controller.rb
/ route  get 'welcome/index' 
/ invoke  erb
/ create    app/views/welcome 
/ create    app/views/welcome/index.html.erb
```

and the rest.. but I can't see the controller in the text editor.

I tried to delete and generate again the controller, and I have also check with ls in the terminal, and it lists the controller, but in my text editor, I don't see the view and the action in the controller. I am using a ruby 2.3.3 in a mac.

Comment: sounds like an issue with your editor try...after generating the controller remove the project from editor and open it again...

Comment: which editor do you use?

Comment: I'm using Atom and iterm3 for the terminal. I tried by removing the project and starting again but same problem, it must be something simple I guess, because I'm a beginner n ruby on rails.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your editor has cached file tree, you need to refresh it.

What is the editor?